# Can Wallaby.js handle multiple test frameworks

Tags: typescript, wallaby.js

Can Wallaby.js handle multiple testFramework values? I'm using typescript and it seems the wallaby config file doesn't need to have the testFramework specified to run jasmine tests.

If I include my qunit tests it errors out on those tests. If I ignore the qunit tests I can get the jasmine tests to run. Is there a way I can configure Wallaby.js to choose the correct framework for each test file?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wallaby.js only supports one testing framework per config file.

Comment: That sounds like I could have two configs in the same solution, one for qunit and one for Jasmine. Would that work? As a side note we are trying to consolidate on Jasmine as our test framework but we started with QUnit so we have about 100 tests in QUnit and 100 in Jasmine.

Comment: Yes, you may have 2 different configs, but can only run one at a time, so not a great experience if you have to edit both test types at the same time. Testing framework consolidation will certainly make things easier (I'm assuming you have to run tests separately even without wallaby because of 2 different frameworks).

Comment: We're currently using Chutzpah to run our tests when developing and on our CI servers and it handles both frameworks simultaneously without issue.